# Comparing props on a custom doesn't work due to invalid hook call error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to compare some props, prev props and new props. I created a hook:

```js
export const RelatedArticles: FC<RelatedArticlesProps> = props => {
  const { content, currentArticle, fetchRelatedContent } = props;

  const usePrevious = <T extends unknown>(value: T): T | undefined => {
    const ref = React.useRef<T>();

    React.useEffect(() => {
      ref.current = value;
    });

    return ref.current;
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (currentArticle) {
      const prevContent = usePrevious(content);
    }

    fetchRelatedContent!(paramSet || {}, RELATED_ARTICLE_LIMIT);
  }, [currentArticle.drupal_id]);

  return(...)
};
```

And I am getting this error:

> Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to 'hoist' your custom hook declaration outside of the component.
Then invoke it inside.

```
export const RelatedArticles: FC<RelatedArticlesProps> = props => {
  const { content, currentArticle, fetchRelatedContent } = props;

 const prevContent = usePrevious(content);
```

Answer (score 1):

Exactly as it says, you can't use hook calls anywhere else but your function component. Your hook call

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  ref.current = value;
});
```

is being called from an anonymous function which is not, in fact, a component.

You can either extract the functionality out of the anonymous function or use a class component. As stated on the link you sent us, it looks like you need to define the function out of your function component.

Comment: So what could I do?

Comment: I know this hook it's been used by other people so what they did to make it work then? => https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-get-previous-props-state-with-react-hooks/

Comment: updated with some details. Anyway why do you use useEffect in another useEffect? I don't get ur intention

Comment: Just move the definition of the function usePrevious out of this function :)